# How to optimize hyper-parameters of a PPO for a gym environment training

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, hyperparameters, ray

I would like to use an optimization algorithm (hyperOptSearch) using ray.tune .
On the official documentation, they use this syntax :

```
tuner = tune.Tuner(
    objective,
    tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
        metric="mean_loss",
        mode="min",
        search_alg=algo,
        num_samples=num_samples,
    ),
    param_space=search_config,
)
results = tuner.fit()
```

where objective is a function to minimize (or maximize) defined as :

```
def evaluate(step, width, height):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return (0.1 + width * step / 100) ** (-1) + height * 0.1



def objective(config):
    for step in range(config["steps"]):
        score = evaluate(step, config["width"], config["height"])
        session.report({"iterations": step, "mean_loss": score})
```

I would like to use this syntaxe, but with an 'evaluate' function evaluating the episode_reward_mean of my gym environment, which is a LunarLander-v2 env.

I recently used this config

```
config = {
             "env": "LunarLander-v2",
             "sgd_minibatch_size": 5000,
             "num_sgd_iter": 50,
             "lr": 5e-5,
             "lambda": 0.8,
             "vf_loss_coeff": 0.7,
             "kl_target": 0.01,
             "kl_coeff": 0.6,
             "entropy_coeff": 0.001,
             "clip_param": 0.38,
             "train_batch_size": 25000,
             # "monitor": True,
             # "model": {"free_log_std": True},

             "num_workers": 1,
             "num_gpus": 0,
             # "batch_mode": "complete_episodes"

         },
```

and this syntaxe to train the model :

```
analysis = tune.Tuner(
    "PPO",  # Algorithme d'IA utilisé

tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
    metric="episode_reward_mean",
    mode="max",
    search_alg=HyperOptSearch(metric="episode_reward_mean", mode="max"),
    # num_samples will repeat the entire config 10 times.
    num_samples=10,
),

param_space=config,

# local_dir="res_LunarLander"
)
results = analysis.fit()
```

What could I do to solve my problem ?

I used to train my model without using any optimization algorithm. I would like to use one to improve my parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your `config` to make use of Tune search space distributions (https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/tutorials/tune-search-spaces.html), which will let you specify lower and upper bounds for possible values in your search space. Without them (as it is in your case), you will only have constant values and thus identical configurations for each trial.

For example, if you want "lr" to be sampled from a logarithmic distribution between `5e-6` and `5e-4`, you'd specify it as `"lr": tune.loguniform(5e-6, 5e-4)`.

Comment: Yes indeed, I forgot to add a grid_search, thank you. But I think the main problem is which function do I have to implement to respect the ray Tuner syntax ? I think the objective function (in the beginning of the post) should calculate the reward of my gym agent. Then the goal should be to maximize the function by passing it in parameter in tune.Tuner. I just don't find any post about the usage of hyperparameters optimization and gym environment.

Comment: RLLib algorithms have all of that already implemented, so if you are using "PPO" as your objective, you shouldn't need to change anything else.

Comment: Thank you, effectively you are wright, it seems to be working.